# How to handle route not found within a namespace in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying expose our app via public APIs. I have written API code as an engine and mounted it on my app.

Say I have defined a route `/api/users` which will be handled by the API engine i have created.

We also have a generic path defined at the end of routes definition which handles all other routes since we use a frontend framework.

If the user misspells the public API as `/api/user-detail`, it gets handled in the generic path defined.

routes.rb

```
mount FtApi::Engine => "/api"
match "*a", controller: :assets, action: :index, via: [:get, :post, :patch]
```

I want to handle any undefined routes error under namespace `api` within the engine, but the path is captured by wildcard route controller.

How can i handle undefined routes error under namespace `api` within the Rails engine defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop capturing any random route by your wildcard by applying Request-Based Constraints.

For more Info take a look here [Request Based Constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) and [Advanced Constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints)

Take a look at the given below code. Haven't tested this but this is an example how you can add constraints in routes.

```
match "*a", controller: :assets, action: :index, constraints: RouteConstraint.new, via: [:get, :post, :patch]
```

And then add this code in constraints or initializers

```
class RouteConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    not request.path.include?('api')
  end
end
```